# Exclude specific product ID and/or categogry in WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

The following code is working to exclude products from the [Dynamic Pricing](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-dynamic-pricing/) discount if they are on sale. Now I would like to extend this function to **also** include specific products and categories (not necessarily in the same function).

Is it sufficient with the ID to add to the if-statement a "or product id = xx" ?

Here's the code so far:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_process_product_discounts', 'is_product_eligible', 10, 4 );

function is_product_eligible( $eligible, $product, $discounter_name, $discounter_object ) {
    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_process_product_discounts', 'is_product_eligible', 10, 4 );

    if ( $product->get_sale_price() ) {
        $eligible = false;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_process_product_discounts', 'is_product_eligible', 10, 4 );

    return $eligible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following that will handle specific product ids and product categories to be defined in the code *(Untested)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_process_product_discounts', 'is_product_eligible', 10, 4 );
function is_product_eligible( $eligible, $product, $discounter_name, $discounter_object ) {
    // Here Define product ids to be excluded
    $product_ids = array( 37, 53 );

    // Here Define product categories to be excluded
    $categories = array( 't-shirts', 'posters' );

    remove_filter( 'woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_process_product_discounts', 'is_product_eligible', 10, 4 );

    if ( $product->get_sale_price() ) {
        $eligible = false;
    }

    // Handling specific product IDS
    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
        $eligible = false;
    }

    // Handling specific product categories
    $product_id = $product->get_parent_id() > 0 ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $eligible = false;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_dynamic_pricing_process_product_discounts', 'is_product_eligible', 10, 4 );

    return $eligible;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.